# SSSD/NSS Slow When Using Sudo

Tags: linux, arch-linux, sudo

I have a server running OpenLDAP, and the issues I am running into is with my client. My client is running SSSD with NSS.

On first boot, I have no issues, and sudo commands are issued fine.

I start having issues after attempting to install or modify a package. Sometimes `aurman` will timeout, other times it will download immediately. When it does make it pass the download, it will freeze on `Creating system user accounts...`, `Creating temporary files...`, or `Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...`.

Below is the result of `sudo journalctl --follow` when `aurman -S accountsservice` executed:

```
Jul 26 16:39:52 test sudo[1400]: REDACTED_USER : problem with defaults entries ; TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/REDACTED_USER ; USER=root ;
Jul 26 16:39:52 test sudo[1399]: REDACTED_USER : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/REDACTED_USER ; USER=root ; COMMAND=validate
Jul 26 16:39:52 test sudo[1400]: REDACTED_USER : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/REDACTED_USER ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/pacman --sync --asdeps -- lightdm
Jul 26 16:39:52 test sudo[1400]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by REDACTED_USER(uid=0)
Jul 26 16:39:53 test systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jul 26 16:39:53 test systemd-fstab-generator[1437]: x-systemd.device-timeout ignored for REDACTED_HOSTNAME:/srv/nfs/home/
Jul 26 16:39:53 test sudo[1400]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 26 16:39:53 test sudo[1449]: REDACTED_USER : problem with defaults entries ; TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/REDACTED_USER ; USER=root ;
Jul 26 16:40:18 test systemd[1]: Failed to get initial list of names: Connection timed out
Jul 26 16:40:25 test dbus-daemon[374]: Unknown username "systemd-timesync" in message bus configuration file
Jul 26 16:40:45 test dbus-daemon[374]: [system] Reloaded configuration
Jul 26 16:41:10 test dbus-daemon[374]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Jul 26 16:41:10 test sudo[1449]: REDACTED_USER : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/REDACTED_USER ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/pacman -D --asexplicit lightdm
Jul 26 16:41:10 test sudo[1449]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by REDACTED_USER(uid=0)
Jul 26 16:41:10 test sudo[1449]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Below is the result of `sudo journalctl --follow` when `sudo -i` is run:

```
Jul 26 17:02:00 test sudo[1645]: REDACTED_USER : problem with defaults entries ; TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/REDACTED_USER ; USER=root ;
Jul 26 17:02:25 test dbus-daemon[374]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Jul 26 17:02:28 test sudo[1645]: pam_sss(sudo:auth): authentication success; logname=REDACTED_USER uid=8102 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=REDACTED_USER rhost= user=REDACTED_USER
Jul 26 17:02:28 test sudo[1645]: REDACTED_USER : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/REDACTED_USER ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash
Jul 26 17:02:28 test sudo[1645]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by REDACTED_USER(uid=0)
```

This is my sssd.conf file:

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
domains = LDAP

[domain/LDAP]
cache_credentials = true
enumerate = true

id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap

ldap_uri = ldaps://REDACTED_HOSTNAME
ldap_search_base = dc=REDACTED,dc=HOST,dc=NAME
ldap_id_use_start_tls = true
ldap_tls_reqcert = demand
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/openldap/certs/slapdcert.pem
ldap_chpass_uri = ldaps://REDACTED_HOSTNAME
```

This is my nsswitch.conf file (NOTE: I have played around with sss on the sudoers, services, and netgroup and same issue):

```
passwd: files sss mymachines systemd
group: files sss mymachines systemd
shadow: files sss
sudoers: files sss

publickey: files

hosts: files mymachines myhostname resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
networks: files

protocols: files
services: files sss
ethers: files
rpc: files

netgroup: files sss
```

Below is the result of doing `time sudo strace -r -o trace_5.log sudo echo hi`, each came at a different time as I was debugging (To reiterate, each line is a different file, and the 25s delay was per `sudo` call):

```
25.007024 recvmsg(6, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="l\3\1\1e\0\0\0\3\0\0\0m\0\0\0\6\1s\0\5\0\0\0", iov_len=24}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
25.025124 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
25.025143 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
25.019033 recvmsg(6, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="l\3\1\1e\0\0\0\3\0\0\0m\0\0\0\6\1s\0\5\0\0\0", iov_len=24}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
25.025170 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
```

The two `openat` calls were when /etc/lcoale.conf existed, when I removed that it stopped. The most common issue was the `recvmsg` call several times.
But `getent hosts` finished fine.
Yet, `getent passwd` takes about 25s and the following shows up in `sudo journctl --follow`:

```
Jul 26 17:11:47 test dbus-daemon[374]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

[EDIT]

When I run `strace -r -o trace_8 getent passwd` I get:

```
25.025198 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
```

Comment: Please include your `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: Got it update, I forgot it the first time, so thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nsswitch.conf "passwd" and "group" modules are in the wrong order: `sss` must be after `systemd`.

When systemd starts a service, it needs to resolve its username (if any) to UID. When dbus-daemon loads its configuration, it also needs to resolve usernames found in security policies to UIDs. This goes through nsswitch the same way as all other user accounts.

Usually these mappings for all system services are found in /etc/passwd (which is the nsswitch "files" module), but perhaps due to a bad decision [(now reverted in Git)](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/5b5d82615011b9827466b7cd5756da35627a1608), a few systemd services do not create their user accounts there – instead they request a dynamic UID through the nsswitch "systemd" module.

In your current configuration a network-based *passwd* module (sss) is listed before the "systemd" module. So whenever systemd or dbus-daemon try to look up the UID for e.g. `systemd-timesyncd`, they end up going through SSSD. But SSSD is queued to start *after* systemd-timesyncd, which results in a deadlock (cyclic dependency, if you want).

Though I suspect that's not the only cause of your problems. But it's almost definitely *a* cause...

Comment: I will test it out in the morning. I have it converted to just nslcd and ldap working. But I can check and see if that will make a difference, I did a lot of things to debug but that isn't one.

Comment: Most likely, nslcd isn't affected as much because its startup does not use systemd-based 'socket activation', unlike SSSD.

Comment: So this was it... I feel relieved and irritated that it was so easy.  I was going off of the ArchWiki LDAP authentication page. Most of the places that explain the set up just briefly show that sss is after files, so I incorrectly assumed that is where it was supposed to be.

Comment: "Remote providers should be after all local providers" would be a better description.

Comment: Totally agree, this would have saved me a day and a half of issues.  I will see if I can get a change on the page.

Comment: The answer is good to address the specific issue at hand, but it is worth mentioning that this strategy partially contradicts the recommendation in the systemd documentation, and can have side effects. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/nss-systemd.html says to place systemd *after* files or compat. One side effect I discovered is that on Ubuntu, the systemd-provided entry for root has a different shell from the one in /etc/passwd. So correct would be files systemd sss. But if you want sss to have precedence over files, that doesn't work either.

Comment: @KevinKeane: I'm not sure which strategy you are referring to, but you almost never want 'sss' to have precedence over 'files'. That's how you get issues such as OP's. If you ever need to have a remote account have precedence over a local account, you do that by deleting the local account.

Comment: @u1686_grawity As usual, it all depends on the specific requirements of a particular situation, but these "almost never" situations exist. I have the exact opposite requirement; for various reasons, some important LDAP accounts need to be duplicated in /etc/passwd, with /etc/passwd only used as a fallback. Granted, not the most common scenario.

Comment: @KevinKeane: Does those accounts' information – UID, shell, homedir – change often enough that /etc/passwd is only a fallback? I doubt the result would be any different if you still had 'files' before LDAP.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I don't want to go into too much detail here beyond that, yes, it's an issue. I'll admit that our authentication infrastructure is more complex than it needs to be, but that's outside my control.